# Is C# files, what kind of encoding should be used within a <script> tag in embedded HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have a C# file with embedded HTML (via `new HtmlString(...)`) where if I am interpolate strings I use `StringObject.EncodeAsHtml()`. However I am not sure if I should use the same encoding method when using strings within `<script>`

```
new HtmlString(
  $"<link rel='manifest' href='{linkToManifest.EncodeAsHtml()}' />" +
  $"<script charset='utf-8'>" +
  $"if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {{" +
  $"navigator.serviceWorker.register('{linkToServiceWorker.EncodeAsHtml()}\" }})" +
  $"}}" +
  $"</script>"
 );
```

The first use of `.EncodeAsHtml()` makes sense, but I am not sure if the second use of it makes as much sense since it is within JavaScript.

Any recommendations?

Comment: The [documentation for HtmlString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.htmlstring?view=netframework-4.8) says *"Represents an HTML-encoded string that should not be encoded again."*  I read that as "you don't have to do it twice."

Comment: I understand, but my question is if I need to use it at all or if I need to use a different method - I'm not trying to run encode the string twice.

Comment: Quite unclear what you want to do with that string. Normal way of figuring it out is carefully walk all steps back from desired output (i.e. HTML page) through every transformation and checking if each piece represented properly. You are right that encoding of links in HTML part and JavaScript part should be different - EncodeAsHtml indeed will not provide  a value suitable for being placed inside quotes in JS (in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you really need to use .EncodeAsHtml() at all in this case.
Also, consider adding type="text/javascript" to the script tag.

Comment: The `type` attribute is best ommited when its value is `text/javascript`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type.

Comment: Is there any encoding I should use? Or can I safely have `$"navigator.serviceWorker.register('{linkToServiceWorker}\" }})"`?